# Invalid Index Path Error

Tags: ios, swift, iglistkit

This Code Seems to be crashing my code.

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'attempt to scroll to invalid
>   index path:  {length = 2, path = 0 - 3}'

```
func handleKeyboardNotification(notification: NSNotification) {

    if let userinfo = notification.userInfo {

        let keyboardFrame = (userinfo[UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as! NSValue).cgRectValue
        self.bottomConstraint?.constant = -(keyboardFrame.height)

        let isKeyboardShowing = notification.name == NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillShow
        self.bottomConstraint?.constant = isKeyboardShowing ? -keyboardFrame.height : 0

        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0, delay: 0, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.curveEaseOut, animations: {
            self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
        }, completion: { (completion) in

            if self.comments.count > 0  && isKeyboardShowing {
                let indexPath = NSIndexPath(item: self.comments.count - 1, section: 0)
                self.collectionView.scrollToItem(at: indexPath as IndexPath, at: .top, animated: true)
            }
        })
    }
}
```

I am also using IGListKit to populate the collection view that this is contained in. Below is my comments controller.

```
import UIKit
import IGListKit
import Firebase

class NewCommentsViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {
    //array of comments which will be loaded by a service function
    var comments = [CommentGrabbed]()
    var messagesRef: DatabaseReference?
    var bottomConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint?
    public var eventKey = ""
    //This creates a lazily-initialized variable for the IGListAdapter. The initializer requires three parameters:
    //1 updater is an object conforming to IGListUpdatingDelegate, which handles row and section updates. IGListAdapterUpdater is a default implementation that is suitable for your usage.
    //2 viewController is a UIViewController that houses the adapter. This view controller is later used for navigating to other view controllers.
    //3 workingRangeSize is the size of the working range, which allows you to prepare content for sections just outside of the visible frame.

    lazy var adapter: ListAdapter = {
        return ListAdapter(updater: ListAdapterUpdater(), viewController: self, workingRangeSize: 0)
    }()

    // 1 IGListKit uses IGListCollectionView, which is a subclass of UICollectionView, which patches some functionality and prevents others.
    let collectionView: UICollectionView = {
        // 2 This starts with a zero-sized rect since the view isn’t created yet. It uses the UICollectionViewFlowLayout just as the ClassicFeedViewController did.
        let view = UICollectionView(frame: CGRect.zero, collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout())
        // 3 The background color is set to white
        view.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
        return view
    }()

    //will fetch the comments from the database and append them to an array
    fileprivate func fetchComments() {

        messagesRef = Database.database().reference().child("Comments").child(eventKey)
        print(eventKey)
        print(comments.count)

        messagesRef?.observe(.childAdded, with: { (snapshot) in
            print(snapshot)

            guard let commentDictionary = snapshot.value as? [String: Any] else {
                return
            }

            print(commentDictionary)

            guard let uid = commentDictionary["uid"] as? String else {
                return
            }

            UserService.show(forUID: uid, completion: { (user) in

                if let user = user {
                    var commentFetched = CommentGrabbed(user: user, dictionary: commentDictionary)
                    commentFetched.commentID = snapshot.key

                    let filteredArr = self.comments.filter { (comment) -> Bool in
                        return comment.commentID == commentFetched.commentID
                    }

                    if filteredArr.count == 0 {
                        self.comments.append(commentFetched)
                    }

                    print(self.comments)

                    self.adapter.performUpdates(animated: true)
                }

                self.comments.sort(by: { (comment1, comment2) -> Bool in
                    return comment1.creationDate.compare(comment2.creationDate) == .orderedAscending
                })

            })
        }, withCancel: { (error) in
            print("Failed to observe comments")
        })

        //first lets fetch comments for current event
    }

    lazy var submitButton: UIButton = {
        let submitButton = UIButton(type: .system)
        submitButton.setTitle("Submit", for: .normal)
        submitButton.setTitleColor(.black, for: .normal)
        submitButton.titleLabel?.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 14)
        submitButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(handleSubmit), for: .touchUpInside)
        submitButton.isEnabled = false

        return submitButton
    }()

    //allows you to gain access to the input accessory view that each view controller has for inputting text
    lazy var containerView: UIView = {
        let containerView = UIView()
        containerView.backgroundColor = .white
        containerView.addSubview(self.submitButton)
        self.submitButton.anchor(top: containerView.topAnchor, left: nil, bottom: containerView.bottomAnchor, right: containerView.rightAnchor, paddingTop: 0, paddingLeft: 0, paddingBottom: 0, paddingRight: 12, width: 50, height: 0)

        containerView.addSubview(self.commentTextField)
        self.commentTextField.anchor(top: containerView.topAnchor, left: containerView.leftAnchor, bottom: containerView.bottomAnchor, right: self.submitButton.leftAnchor, paddingTop: 0, paddingLeft: 12, paddingBottom: 0, paddingRight: 180, width: 0, height: 0)
        self.commentTextField.delegate = self

        let lineSeparatorView = UIView()
        lineSeparatorView.backgroundColor = UIColor.rgb(red: 230, green: 230, blue: 230)
        containerView.addSubview(lineSeparatorView)
        lineSeparatorView.anchor(top: containerView.topAnchor, left: containerView.leftAnchor, bottom: nil, right: containerView.rightAnchor, paddingTop: 0, paddingLeft: 0, paddingBottom: 0, paddingRight: 0, width: 0, height: 0.5)

        return containerView
    }()

    lazy var commentTextField: UITextField = {
        let textField = UITextField()
        textField.placeholder = "Add a comment"
        textField.delegate = self
        textField.addTarget(self, action: #selector(textFieldDidChange(_:)), for: .editingChanged)

        return textField
    }()

    func textFieldDidChange(_ textField: UITextField) {
        let isCommentValid = commentTextField.text?.characters.count ?? 0 > 0

        if isCommentValid {
            submitButton.isEnabled = true
        } else {
            submitButton.isEnabled = false
        }
    }

    func handleSubmit() {

        guard let comment = commentTextField.text, comment.characters.count > 0 else {
            return

        }

        let userText = Comments(content: comment, uid: User.current.uid, profilePic: User.current.profilePic!)
        sendMessage(userText)

        // will remove text after entered
        self.commentTextField.text = nil
    }

    func flagButtonTapped (from cell: CommentCell) {

        guard let indexPath = collectionView.indexPath(for: cell) else { return }

        // 2
        let comment = comments[indexPath.item]

        // 3
        let alertController = UIAlertController(title: nil, message: nil, preferredStyle: .actionSheet)

        // 4
        if comment.uid != User.current.uid {
            let flagAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Report as Inappropriate", style: .default) { _ in
                ChatService.flag(comment)

                let okAlert = UIAlertController(title: nil, message: "The post has been flagged.", preferredStyle: .alert)
                okAlert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: .default))

                self.present(okAlert, animated: true)
            }

            let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel, handler: nil)
            alertController.addAction(cancelAction)
            alertController.addAction(flagAction)
        } else {
            let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel, handler: nil)

            let deleteAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Delete Comment", style: .default, handler: { _ in
                ChatService.deleteComment(comment, self.eventKey)

                let okAlert = UIAlertController(title: nil, message: "Comment Has Been Deleted", preferredStyle: .alert)
                okAlert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: .default))

                self.present(okAlert, animated: true)
            })

            alertController.addAction(cancelAction)
            alertController.addAction(deleteAction)
        }

        present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    func handleKeyboardNotification(notification: NSNotification) {

        if let userinfo = notification.userInfo {

            let keyboardFrame = (userinfo[UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as! NSValue).cgRectValue
            self.bottomConstraint?.constant = -keyboardFrame.height

            let isKeyboardShowing = notification.name == NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillShow
            self.bottomConstraint?.constant = isKeyboardShowing ? -keyboardFrame.height : 0

            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0, delay: 0, options: .curveEaseOut, animations: {
                self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
            }, completion: { (completion) in
                if self.comments.count > 0  && isKeyboardShowing {
                    let indexPath = NSIndexPath(item: self.comments.count - 1, section: 0)
                    self.collectionView.scrollToItem(at: indexPath as IndexPath, at: .top, animated: true)
                }
            })
        }
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        view.addSubview(collectionView)
        collectionView.addSubview(containerView)
        collectionView.alwaysBounceVertical = true

        view.addConstraintsWithFormatt("H:|[v0]|", views: containerView)
        view.addConstraintsWithFormatt("V:[v0(48)]", views: containerView)
        bottomConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: containerView, attribute: .bottom, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: view, attribute: .bottom, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
        view.addConstraint(bottomConstraint!)

        adapter.collectionView = collectionView
        adapter.dataSource = self

        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(handleKeyboardNotification), name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillShow, object: nil)
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(handleKeyboardNotification), name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillHide, object: nil)

        collectionView.register(CommentCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "CommentCell")

        fetchComments()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)

        tabBarController?.tabBar.isHidden = true
        submitButton.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    }

    //viewDidLayoutSubviews() is overridden, setting the collectionView frame to match the view bounds.
    override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
        super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()

        collectionView.frame = view.bounds
    }

}

extension NewCommentsViewController: ListAdapterDataSource {

    // 1 objects(for:) returns an array of data objects that should show up in the collection view. loader.entries is provided here as it contains the journal entries.
    func objects(for listAdapter: ListAdapter) -> [ListDiffable] {
        print("comments = \(comments)")

        return comments
    }

    // 2 For each data object, listAdapter(_:sectionControllerFor:) must return a new instance of a section controller. For now you’re returning a plain IGListSectionController to appease the compiler — in a moment, you’ll modify this to return a custom journal section controller.
    func listAdapter(_ listAdapter: ListAdapter, sectionControllerFor object: Any) -> ListSectionController {
        //the comment section controller will be placed here but we don't have it yet so this will be a placeholder
        return CommentsSectionController()
    }

    // 3 emptyView(for:) returns a view that should be displayed when the list is empty. NASA is in a bit of a time crunch, so they didn’t budget for this feature.
    func emptyView(for listAdapter: ListAdapter) -> UIView? {
        let view = UIView()
        view.backgroundColor = UIColor.white

        return view
    }
}

extension NewCommentsViewController {

    func sendMessage(_ message: Comments) {
        ChatService.sendMessage(message, eventKey: eventKey)
    }
}
```

Also this is my section controller. Now it is loading the data but as soon as I try to add someething to test if it is working properly using the keyboard it crashes.

```
import UIKit
import IGListKit
import Foundation

class CommentsSectionController: ListSectionController {

    var comment: CommentGrabbed?

    override init() {
        super.init()

        inset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: 15, right: 0)
    }

    // MARK: IGListSectionController Overrides
    override func numberOfItems() -> Int {
        print(numberOfItems)

        return 1
    }

    override func sizeForItem(at index: Int) -> CGSize {
        let frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: collectionContext!.containerSize.width, height: 50)
        let dummyCell = CommentCell(frame: frame)
        dummyCell.comment = comment
        dummyCell.layoutIfNeeded()

        let targetSize = CGSize(width: collectionContext!.containerSize.width, height: 55)
        let estimatedSize = dummyCell.systemLayoutSizeFitting(targetSize)
        let height = max(40 + 8 + 8, estimatedSize.height)

        return CGSize(width: collectionContext!.containerSize.width, height: height)
    }

    override var minimumLineSpacing: CGFloat {
        get {
            return 0.0
        }
        set {
            self.minimumLineSpacing = 0.0
        }
    }

    override func cellForItem(at index: Int) -> UICollectionViewCell {

        guard let cell = collectionContext?.dequeueReusableCell(of: CommentCell.self, for: self, at: index) as? CommentCell else {
            fatalError()
        }

        print(comment)

        cell.comment = comment

        return cell
    }

    override func didUpdate(to object: Any) {
        comment = object as! CommentGrabbed
    }

    override func didSelectItem(at index: Int) {

    }
}
```

This specific method is responsbile for returning cells

```
func listAdapter(_ listAdapter: ListAdapter, sectionControllerFor object: Any) -> ListSectionController {
    //the comment section controller will be placed here but we don't have it yet so this will be a placeholder
    return CommentsSectionController()
}
```

Any insight would be very helpful

Answer (score 1):

This is happening because you set the number of items for your collection to be equal to 1, but you are trying to access a cell that has an index equal to `IndexPath(section: 0, item: self:comments.count-1)`, and `comments.count-1` is equal to 3 in this case as you can guess from the error log, which is why you get this error.

The solution here would be returning the correct amount of comments (`comments.count-1`) for your collection view data source.

**UPDATE:**

In that case, you should not use `NSIndexPath`. Instead, use `IndexPath`. Also, after this change you no longer need to cast your index path as IndexPath in your scrollToItem call. The updated version would look like this:

```
func handleKeyboardNotification(notification: NSNotification) {

        // ...

        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0, delay: 0, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.curveEaseOut, animations: {
            self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
        }, completion: { (completion) in
            if self.comments.count > 0  && isKeyboardShowing {
                let indexPath = IndexPath(item: self.comments.count-1, section: 0)
                self.collectionView.scrollToItem(at: indexPath, at: .top, animated: true)
            }
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: How would I do that inside of the function when I have no access to comments inside there

Comment: I looked again at your code and since you seem to be using a third-party library (IGListKit) and your implementation looks fine because you are setting the number of comments in your  objects(for listAdapter: ListAdapter) -> [ListDiffable] data source method, but according to the documentation you may want to consider removing the workingRangeSize from your list adapter's initializer when your size is 0.

Comment: Also I would recommend you using a minimal and verifiable code when you post a question, it will make us easier to find the problem inside of your code, but I am thinking it's probably related to your message observe method and it's very likely that you're trying to access the array of comments at a certain path before the your data source gets filled

Comment: For example I cannot find where you are reloading your collection view (or inserting/deleting your cells) in your code after you got the data from the comment/message observer, is there something related to this in your adapter's performUpdates method?

Comment: yes the performUpdares method I call in fetch comments takes care of that

Comment: the reloading of data that is

Comment: in effect a section controller is a cell I beleive @Alex

Comment: Will test it now @Alex

Comment: Um it crashed again

Comment: Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'attempt to scroll to invalid index path: <NSIndexPath: 0x60000023a0c0> {length = 2, path = 0 - 2}'

Comment: that is definetly the method that crashes it though